# Why can't you divide by 0 in an Edwards Curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The equation of an Edwards curve is $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + d x^2 y^2 \,$

The addition formula is $(x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2) = \left( \frac{x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1}{1 + dx_1 x_2 y_1 y_2}, \frac{y_1 y_2 - x_1 x_2}{1 - dx_1 x_2 y_1 y_2} \right) \,$

What is the intuitive explanation that $dx_1 x_2 y_1 y_2$ can't be equal to ± 1 when d is a non-square? Because I don't see why you can't have $x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 = ± \frac{1}{d}$

Answer (score 2):

I’m not at all familiar with this representation of an elliptic curve, but I think that when you homogenize, to the equation $x^2z^2+y^2z^2=z^4+dx^2y^2$, things may get a bit clearer. The points $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ on the line at infinity are singular, seems to me, and even before writing the addition-rule projectively, I’ll wager that the sum of any two nonsingular points will again be nonsingular. But then I haven’t checked this.

**EDIT**: After looking more closely, I realize that the situation is complicated enough that it requires careful description. For typographical and esthetic reasons, I’m changing your description somewhat. The condition that $d$ be a nonsquare means that the points at infinity are not $k$-rational, where $k$ is the constant field (characteristic $\ne2$ necessarily). This makes sense arithmetically, but geometrically it does not. So, in my description of the curve, I’ll use the equation $$x^2+y^2=1+D^2x^2y^2$$ instead. It makes all the formulas simpler. I should say that I have the real picture in mind, with $D>1$, and this is how it looks:

Start with a U-shaped curve, open upwards, centered on the positive $y$-axis, with its vertex (lowest point) at $(0,1)$, and with asymptotes $x=\pm1/D$. Then take this, and rotate it $\pi/2$ repeatedly, till you have four of these, opening out in all four directions. This is your quartic curve.

For this curve, I want to take a different but isomorphic law of combination:
\begin{align}
(x,y)+(x',y')&=\left(\frac{xx'-yy'}{1-D^2xx'yy'},\frac{xy'+x'y}{1+D^2xx'yy'}\right)\\
\Bbb O&=(1,0)\\
-(x,y)&=(x,-y)\,,
\end{align}
so that the neutral point $\Bbb O$ is the vertex of the U-shaped curve that sits straddling the positive $x$-axis.
I’ve made this change only because your original law had the sine addition formula in the numerator of the $x$-coordinate, and the negative of the cosine formula in the $y$-coordinate, and that annoyed me. We can call the other three vertices $\Bbb P_{\pi/2}$, $\Bbb P_\pi$, and $\Bbb P_{3\pi/2}$.

Now, when you look at the equation for the curve, you see that its highest-degree form is just $x^2y^2$, and this tells you how the curve intersects the line at infinity: at $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. But the exponents tell you that these points are two-fold intersections with that line. Indeed, they’re the intersections with the four asymptotes I mentioned above.

**Very** crudely, we can desingularize our curve by designating four points at infinity $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_+$, $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_-$, $\Bbb I^\uparrow_+$, and $\Bbb I^\uparrow_-$. The first of these, $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_+$, can be thought of as $(\infty,1/D)$ or maybe the limit of $(t,1/D)$ as $t\to\infty$, even though these points are not on the curve. In a similar way, $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_-$ is $(\infty,-1/D)$, and you can guess the others.
Let’s see how this works out by seeing what the sum $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_++\Bbb I^\rightarrow_+$ will turn out to be. The formula gives
$$
\left(\frac{t^2-1/D^2}{1-D^2t^2/D^2},\frac{2t/D}{1+D^2t^2/D^2}\right) \longrightarrow
(-1,0)=\Bbb P_\pi\,.
$$

You easily check, using the formulas, that $[2]\bigl(\Bbb P_\pi\bigr)=\Bbb O$, which shows that $\Bbb I^\rightarrow_+$ is a four-division point on our curve. Furthermore, you also see that $[2]\bigl(\Bbb P_{\pi/2}\bigr)=\Bbb P_\pi$.

Without working (!), we’ve found eight rational points on our curve: all division points, and since there are too many $4$-division points for a cyclic group, you see that the torsion is at least $C_2\oplus C_4$, where $C_n$ means cyclic of order $n$.

**Now, finally**, to answer your question about infinities, it’s clear. Any time your addition formula leads you to a point on the line at infinity, it’ll be of form $(\infty,\pm1/D)$ or $(\pm1/D,\infty)$, where here, “$\infty$” refers to an expression that blows up with zero in the denominator. But if $D=\sqrt d$ is not $k$-rational, then your formulas with coefficients in $k$ can not lead you to $1/\sqrt d$.

Comment: IIRC, $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is a better home than $\mathbb{P}^2$, but I may be misremembering.

Comment: Oh! Also, singular vs nonsingular isn't the issue. Compare to Weierstrass form, where the addition formula breaks down when you try to add a point to itself. While in any form the addition formula must break down someplace, Edwards form is notable because it doesn't happen when adding points defined over the base field; you have to go up to a quadratic extension.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I’m pretty sure you’re right. I wish I knew more about this form. But I’m feeling much too lazy today to work things out. As to $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$, ordinarily a single affine equation in two variables wants to become a single homogeneous equation in three variables.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I have succumbed to the blandishments of this form of elliptic curve, but have not gotten far in improving my understanding. I think the story is more complicated than either of us realized, since there are two points on the line at infinity, both singular, nodal (two different tangent directions).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to leave here a comment that an Edward's curve $x^2+y^2=1+dx^2y^2$ is isomorphic to a curve in Weierstrass form of the form:
$$Y^2 = X^3 + (-4d - 4)X^2 - 64dX + 256d^2 + 256d.$$
I don't think this is particularly useful here, but I was curious to see a Weierstrass model... so here it is. The torsion subgroup is generically $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $(8 ,-16d + 16)$. If $d$ is a square, then we gain another point of order $2$, as Lubin points out in another response, and we get a torsion subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.